# How can i put the child div on the right top?

Tags: css

i have two divs, i want to put the child on top of the parent top, i was trying but the child div got stuck outside, what is the wrong?

```css
.content {
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 140px;
  min-width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.topcorner {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="topcorner">top</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking, but does adding `position: relative;` to the `content` works for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent element needs to have `position: relative`.

Add `position: relative` to the parent class `.content` to make the child div inside the parent div.

```css
.content {
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 140px;
  min-width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative; //Add this line
}

.topcorner {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="topcorner">top</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working for resizable cells....